# Big M constraint question

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a question regarding using Big M constraints to solve the following problem:

Given: $a, b \ge 0$ and integers.

$$2a + 5b \le 17\\
a + b \le 5\\
3a + 6b \le 20$$

For at least two of the constraints, use linear constraints and integer variables to satisfy the above constraints.

Comment: i got the Big M values for x a x <=5 and for y <=3.3333